# Ошибка non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, selenium

```
//public void ExcelUpdate(String error, int ID) throws FilloException {
    Connection con2 = fillo.getConnection("E:\\QA Java\\LastQATraineeProject\\excelFiles\\SecondTable.xlsx");
    String data2;
    if (RegistrationPageC.ErrorAppeared(error)) {
        data2 = "Update Лист1 Set result = 'Successfully!' Where ID = " + ID + "";
    }
    else {
        data2 = "Update Лист1 Set result = 'Unsuccessfully!' Where ID = " + ID + "";
    }
    con2.executeQuery(data2);
    con2.close();
}

    
public String ErrorDisplay() {
    return ErrorWindow.getText();
}
    
public boolean ErrorAppeared(String error) {
    if (ErrorDisplay().contains(error)) {
        Assert.assertEquals(ErrorDisplay(), error);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: думаете того, что вы привели, достаточно для понимания вашей проблемы?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не дописал толком, вроде бы исправил.
В целом тут впервые закидываю вопрос, потому коряво сделал, извините.)

Comment: я думаю вам поможет руководство как задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Ошибка, что вы получаете, говорит о том, что вы не-статическую переменную в статической функции пытаетесь использовать, что невозможно сделать, вот компилятор и ругается. Код ваш мне ни о чем не говворит ес честно.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку и да, понимаю, что залил всё в отвратительном виде, но не нашёл, можно ли залить именно файл сюда, точнее 2 файла, тест и класс, потому закинул частями.

Comment: Файлы заливать не надо. Надо сделать [минимальный и самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), а он у вас 3 строчки займет. Изолируйте вашу прблему, поглядите так тот конкретный участок кода, что у вас не работает, сделайте митинимальный пример по нему и копируйте сюда, чтобы мы могли запустить и увидеть вашу ошибку. И на забудьте перед этим воспольщоваться поиском, я думаю вы не первый тут с такой ошибкой

Comment: например, [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-static+variable+this+cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static+context)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите ваш метод `main()` + остальные статические методы. Скорее всего виноваты вложенные классы, либо это попытка обращения к полям экземпляра из статического метода класса.